# I can't connect to the database with angularjs and spring boot mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to integrate AngularJS in my Spring Boot MVC project but I can't understand how to connect it to Spring Boot through `@RequestMapping` and `@GetMapping`.

When I get the project locally I don't detect any error on chrome Google Developer Tools.

This is my Controller

```
var main = angular.module('main', []);
main.component('main', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.template.jsp',
});

main.controller('CaseJson', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('caseprod/all')
      .then(function(response, status) {
          $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      }, function(err) {
        console.error("Error", err);
      });
 });

 main.controller('getcontroller', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.getfunction = function(){
      var url = $location.absUrl() + "caseprod/all";

      $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        $scope.response = response.data
      }, function error(response) {
        $scope.postResultMessage = "Error with status: " +  response.statusText;
      });
    }
 })
```

I tried with both controllers
And this is where it should display:

```
<div data-ng-controller="getcontroller">
    <div var="current" data-ng-repeat="case in response">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img data-ng-src="{{data.img}}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="user-info">
                <h2>"{{data.nome}}"</h2>
                <span>"{{data.annoFondazione}}"</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the controller spring

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/caseprod")
public class CaseProduttriciController {

@Autowired
private CaseProduttriciService caseprodservice;

@GetMapping(value = "/all", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<CaseProduttrici> findAll(){
    return caseprodservice.findAll();
}
```

If you need something else, tell me. Thanks

Comment: you need to use complete spring boot resource URL including the hostname e.g. localhost:8080/caseprod/all as spring boot run over embedded Apache server

Comment: please use a common language - english would be helpful to understand

Comment: Sorry Nitesh. I tried with
$ http.get ('localhost: 8080 / caseprod / all')
and in the second controller with
var url = "localhost: 8080 / caseprod / all";
but it displays nothing and no errors on Google Developer Tools

Comment: Have you checked for your server port? Is it really 8080? what's your application.properties say?

Comment: if there is no entry for server.port in application.properties then add one for customization like server.port=8081 as By default, Spring Boot uses the 8080 port number to start the Tomcat

Comment: On application.properties of spring i have set spring.datasource.url=dbc:mysql://localhost:3306/filmatografia?serverTimezone=UTC. I tried 3306 too but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

spring.datasource.url=dbc:mysql
Is it normal that you miss "j" in jdbc ?
What are showing your logs ?

Comment: spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/filmatografia?serverTimezone=UTC I'm sorry I don't know why it didn't show j. Could you tell me which logs I should look at?

Comment: Do you have an error in your Spring project when you call it directly (not with your Angular but with the spring url -> localhost:8080/...)  ?
In the meantime, can you print "url " in your angular project ?

Comment: Hi jlh91! 
no no errors in my spring boot project I insert the View Controller to show how I open my main page. '@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String viewCaseProduttrici(ModelMap caseproduttrici) {
  caseproduttrici.addAttribute("listCP", caseprcontr.findAll());
  return "index";
 }'